# How to test a pressure control solenoid valve?

Tags: solenoid-valve

I have tested the resistance of the solenoid valve (variable force solenoid) and it was 3.6 ohm, however, when I connected it to a square 9V battery, the plunger didn't move. Does that mean it's faulty?

This the solenoid valve I have :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you must make sure the solenoid is rated for 9 volts DC. If it is, you must consider the type of battery. The 3.6 ohm coil would draw 2.5 amps for an ideal 9 volt source. A 9 volt alkaline battery may add a 1 or 2 ohm internal resistance to that reducing the current to 1.6 to 2 amps. A 9 volt zinc carbon battery might add more than 30 ohms, reducing the current to less than half an amp.

Information from comments and another post indicates that this valve may have been removed from a motor vehicle and that vehicle likely has a 12-volt electrical system. The expression "(variable force solenoid)" in the question implies that the valve may work with variable voltage. It seems likely that the solenoid may operate close to 12 volts under some conditions. It probably should be tested by applying 12 volts DC from a source that will not experience a significant voltage drop with a 3.3 amp current draw. It would be best to apply voltage for only a few seconds. If there is no movement, the solenoid is probably bad. It would be preferable to refer to the vehicle service manual.

Comment: Yeah, the plunger has engaged on a 12V battery, but the solenoid was very hot

Answer (score 1):

No, it means that the battery can not supply enough current to activate the solenoid.

You need to find the manufacturer's datasheet for the solenoid and use a power supply with the required voltage and current capabilities.

Comment: I dont have access to the datasheet, I have looked everywhere and couldn't find it. Is it safe to apply 12V voltage to a PWM solenoid valve?

Comment: @JohnSall,  no way of really knowing without a datasheet.  Safe is relative.  It's MUCH safer if you have a spare solenoid!

Comment: @John Sall "PWM solenoid valve"? How do you know that it is PWM operated? Why is that not mentioned in the question? What else do you that you are not telling us?

Comment: @CharlesCowie I did mention above that it is a variable force solenoid